# Breaking up a string by comparing characters/combinations of characters against a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops, dictionary

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
testdictionary = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "A":4}
list1 = []
list2 = []
keyval = 200
for char in string:
    i = 0
    y = "".join(list1)
    while y in testdictionary:
        list1.append(string[i])
        i +=1
    list2.append(y[:-1])
    testdictionary[y] = keyval
    keyval +=1
    string = string[((len(list1))-1):]
    list1 = []
```

So for a string "abcacababa" the desired output would be:

```
['ab', 'ca', 'cab', 'aba']
```

Or "AAAAA" would be

```
['A', 'AA'. 'AA']
```

Take `abcacababa`. Iterating through we get `a` which is in `testdictionary` so we append `list1` again. This time we have `ab` which is not in the dictionary, so we add it as a key to `testdictionary` with a value of 200. Then doing the same process again, we add `ca` to `testdictionary` with a value of 201. Then since we have already added `ca`, the next value appended to `list2` would be `cab` and so on.

What I am trying to do is take a string and compare each character against a dictionary, if the character is a key in the dictionary add another character, do this until it is not in the dictionary at which point add it to the dictionary and assign a value to it, keep doing this for the whole string.

There's obviously a lot wrong with this code, it also doesn't work. The `i` index being out of range but I have no idea how to approach this iteration. Also I need to add in an if statement to ensure the "leftovers" of the string at the end are appended to `list2`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't understand the example inputs and outputs. Can you walk through more explicitly one or both of them?

Comment: Yep, what @rbierman said - your problem description has to be a lot more explicit and clear, perhaps with a few more detailed examples. Nobody can help you fix code that's supposed to do something that you've mostly described in non-working code.

Comment: @rbierman, Just edited post to fix dictionary. Take `abcacababa`. Iterating through we get `a` which is in `testdictionary` so we append `list1` again. This time we have `ab` which is not in the dictionary, so we add it as a key to `testdictionary` with a value of 200. Then doing the same process again, we add `ca` to `testdictionary`with a value of 201. Then since we have already added `ca`, the next value appended to `list2` would be `cab` and so on. I hope this clears it up a little bit at least, apologies for not having clarity in my explanation.

Comment: Put this stuff in your question, not the comments, @Boa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it now @Boa. This code I believe works for `abcacababa` at least. As for leftovers, I think it's only possible to have a single 'leftover' key when the last key is in the test dictionary, so you just have to check after the loop if `curr_key` is not empty:

```
testdictionary = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "A":4}
word = 'abcacababa'

key_val = 200
curr_key = ''

out_lst = []
let_ind = 0

for let in word:
    curr_key += let
    if curr_key not in testdictionary:
        out_lst.append(curr_key)
        testdictionary[curr_key] = key_val
        key_val += 1
        curr_key = ''

leftover = curr_key
print(out_lst)
print(testdictionary)
```

Output:

```
['ab', 'ca', 'cab', 'aba']
{'a': 1, 'A': 4, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'aba': 203, 'ca': 201, 'ab': 200, 'cab': 202}
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear. Also I think your second example with `AAAAA` should be `['AA', 'AAA']` instead of `['A', 'AA', 'AA']`